# Android google map version 2 shows blank white page?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-v2

In my application am using Google map version 2.When i run the application in real device through eclipse means it shows the map.but when i export the application as signed apk and am upload my apk in play store.Then i download the uploaded apk file from play store and am run it in my device but it shows only blank white page.i don't know whats the problem.Can any know.please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to require `signed apk with SHA-1`

**Step 1:**

```
Now locate to jdk in C drive(Considering for windows and assigning C drive)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\A.keystore -alias A

So it will create SHA-1 finger print
```

**Step 2:**

```
    Go to google api console.
    Generate new api key for android you have to used this SHA-1 and current playstore package name.
    Put Api key into your map.
```

I hope this is enough for you.If any **query put comment**.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you sign an application it's **SHA1 fingerprint** changes.

So when you make it **a signed application** take the SHA1 which eclipse gave you on signing proccess and write it to the allowing applications in [Google API CONSOLE](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1)

Answer (score 1):

you need to create map key using your keystore.

1) so generate sha-1 using your keystore rather debug.keystore.

2) Go to google api console

3) generate new key for android

4) and pass this new SHA-1 with your package name

5) put that map key in your code

Answer (score 1):

This is because after when you are export your Signed apk of your application then its SHA1 fingerprint changes.

SO you need to go by this way:

```
1) Generate sha-1 using your keystore rather debug.keystore.

2) Go to google api console

3) generate new key for android

4) and pass this new SHA-1 with your package name

5) put that map key in your code
```

and use this one:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

You are using debug key and exporting your apk. use release key. Hope this might help.

> [Google Map Android API v2 can't display map in play store application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395764/google-map-android-api-v2-cant-display-map-in-play-store-application/18395821#18395821)

Answer (score 1):

To export the APK with google map you have to use release key while exporting rather than debug.keystore.

Use this method to generate Release key for google map API v2.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore "C:\Users\cp
01\.android\releasekey.ketstore" -alias release_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
-validity 10000
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:
What is the name of your organizational unit?
 [Unknown]:
What is the name of your organization?
 [Unknown]:
What is the name of your City or Locality?
 [Unknown]:
What is the name of your State or Province?
 [Unknown]:
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
 [Unknown]:
 Is CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
 [no]:  yes

 Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA1withRSA) wit
   a validity of 10,000 days
    for: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknow

  Enter key password for <release_alias>
       (RETURN if same as keystore password):
  Re-enter new password:
  [Storing C:\Users\cpc01\.android\releasekey.ketstore]





C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin>keytool -list -v -alias release_alias -ke
store c:\Users\cpc01\.android\releasekey.ketstore
Enter keystore password:
Alias name: release_alias
Creation date: Jul 25, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
Issuer: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
Serial number: 51f0c02c
Valid from: Thu Jul 25 11:35:32 IST 2013 until: Mon Dec 10 11:35:32 IST 2040
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  your md5 Fingure print
     SHA1: your SHA1 fingure print
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

Now use SHA1 fingure print toregister the app on API console

I hope this will help you lot....
Accept answer if helpful to you.. thanks
Enjoy Coding