# Google map v2 doesn't work in play store

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I created an android app that shows google map using Google Map api V2 and it works well with me in my mobile. 
But when I uploaded the apk of this app to (Google play store), it doesn't show my map.

Could anyone tell me why? and how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved it by this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711342/android-google-map-version-2-shows-blank-white-page

Answer (score 5):

Your Maps API key is tied to the SHA1 signature of the keystore that is used to sign the app .apk. When you run your app from eclipse, a debug keystore is used, when you export your app for release, you use a 'real' keystore (it's SHA1 fingerprint is shown at the end of eclipse's export wizard).

So you have to create another Maps API key (to put in your manifest) corresponding with you release keystore for release.

Check Google's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#displaying_certificate_information).

Comment: I Took SHA1 key from List and generated the new key and give SHA1 key with my packagename
as following
03:D8:EF:05:04:CF:06:86:15:1A:F1:D3:B1:18:46:F5:xx:xx:xx:xx;packagename
and I Puted the new map api key in my manifest. I done this and I see map in the device but not in the google play so I can't understand what I have to do again? could you tell me the steps ??

Comment: @Eman87  keytool -list -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore C:\Users\myUser\.android\android.jks -storepass mystorepass -keypass mykeypass

Answer (score 1):

This is simple method. Select your project->Right click->Export android application. Fill all requirements. When exporting it will show your SHA 1 finger print. copy that and paste it along with package name in google console. You can see Certificate finger prints in screenshot.Use that SHA1 key.

[image]

Comment: it gives me the following screen: http://dt-works.com/emy/9-12-2013%203-08-31%20PM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are using signed api key when you are exporting. Otherwise map looks blank.

Signed apk for release key procedure is here

> [Google Map Android API v2 can't display map in play store application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395764/google-map-android-api-v2-cant-display-map-in-play-store-application/18395821#18395821)

Comment: when I use the following command:  

keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Dt4IT\.android\A.keystore -alias A 

it gives me the following error:

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Dt4IT
\.android\A.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Dt4IT\.android\A.key
store
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(Unknown Source)

Comment: i have given reference where A is ur pjt apk ie when u export and sign it right,for that you will generate keystore.so you want to compare that keystore file

Comment: I tried the steps in the link and I uploaded it again but it still show maps when run from eclipse but when install from google play it not work.

Comment: you signed your apk and checked? @Eman87 still map is in blank?

Comment: yes I signed and created the keystore file and get the SHA-1 then generated the api_key then added to my manifest.xml, when I run from eclipse to my mobile, it works well but when I uploaded to play store then install, it gives me blank page. :S

Comment: it takes some time to update in google play store.when u updated?

Comment: I uploaded yesterday.

Comment: I'm using java jre7 instead sdk in eclipse and I used the (C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool), is this cause the blank issue ??