# Google Maps Api v2 issue in android phone

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have recently created a android google maps application using google api maps v2 ,

map working very good when i am testing it on my phone but after creating signed application package of apk file, maps do not work. In that activity only white screen is visible in the place of map.

what should i do please someone help me in sort out this issue.

Comment: did you signed with debug.keystore or something other?

Comment: Do you turn on your internet connection while testing application in other phone ?

Comment: @Andy refer my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711342/android-google-map-version-2-shows-blank-white-page/18711508#18711508) my answer.

Problem with `signed apk` with `unsigned` **debug.keystroke**