# Display google map in app showing white screen after updated in playstore

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

I checked lots of answer to solve this issue,but i didnt get proper solution to solve my bug.

Created api key with the sha1 finger print,using this link http://hmkcode.com/getting-android-google-maps-v2-api-key/

if i generate the api key in my machine,while running my app in my device its working fine.if my friend runs the same code in his machine means,map view is showing white screen.

layout.xml

```
 <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="136dp"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

      />
```

location.java
its in oncreate method

```
 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                private void mapview(String lattit, String longi) {
                    double newlat=Double.parseDouble(lattit);
                    double newlongi=Double.parseDouble(longi);


                      if(map !=null){
                           // Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                              //  .title("Hamburg"));
                            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(newlat, newlongi)).title("Hello Maps ");
                            map.addMarker(marker);
                           // Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                             //   .position(KIEL)
                              //  .title("Kiel")
                              //  .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                               // .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                 //   .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
                            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                            LatLng Newone = new LatLng(newlat, newlongi);

                            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
                            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Newone, 15));

                            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
                      }


            }
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
 <permission
        android:name="com.companyname.appname.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.companyname.appname.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
                       <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="key"  />


    </application>
```

with these code only i generated sha1 key too

keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
[image: here i took the path]

Comment: Have you checked with your key?

Comment: try getting SHA1 fingerprint from Preferences-->Android-->Build  see if both are same...

Comment: i am using olderversion of eclipse,so its showing only C:\Users\karthick\.android\debug.keystore @Hardeep

Comment: @KarthickM you are not using release API key.

Comment: no i am not using that key @Yugesh

Comment: i am 99% sure there is a problem with that google key either at the time of creating or at the time of using..Please check your package name while creating it and cross check your SHA1 fingerprint

Comment: @KarthickM So that's the problem.

Comment: @Yugesh while generating sha1 i am using debug.keystore;but while uploading into playstore i am using release key only

Comment: @KarthickM Refer this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711342/android-google-map-version-2-shows-blank-white-page)

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\A.keystore -alias A ,so you mean to say i need to use like this; in the place of E:\A.keystore i need to use C:\Users\Karthick\.android\debug.keystore is it?? @Yugesh

Comment: @Yugesh this is my release key C:\Users\Karthick\workspace2\Mykey

Comment: @KarthickM I give one simple solution for that at time of create apk with key store file,at last step you select the .APK destination path am right.In that place it shows **SHA1** finger print that's the release **SHA1** finger print to generate `release Key`.

Comment: @Yugesh no dude,while create signed apk,i used my existing release key only,there i never saw sha1 fingerprint

Comment: @KarthickM what are all things show it in the window before click the finish button to generate .APK.

Comment: @Yugesh have u seen the image