# Authorization failure while loading google maps v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an android app with google maps:-

My steps:-

1. Main activity extends `Fragment activity`
2. Made a copy of Google play services library and imported it to eclipse.Further added a reference of the library to the project.
3. Enabled the build target of the project to Google API's 4.4.2
4. Created a browser key on Google API console.
5. Created an SHA1 certificate for the app in eclipse using the keytool plugin(Also verifies the key using the traditional command prompt technique and both match).
6. Created an android Api key on Google API console using the SHA1 key obtained

Issue:- I get a blank map on the screen with the zoom in and zoom out buttons

Here is my code:-

activity_main.xml:-

```
  <fragment

     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"

   />
```

AndroidManifest.xml :-

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <permission
        android:name="com.strangeworld.locations.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.strangeworld.locatorapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD2LVShEdbQWWV4......"/>

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
```

Log cat:-

```
 01-10 10:33:28.059: E/dalvikvm(2440): Could not find class 'maps.ae.i', referenced from method maps.af.al.a
01-10 10:33:30.039: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2440): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-10 10:33:32.909: E/Google Maps Android API(2440): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-10 10:33:32.929: E/Google Maps Android API(2440): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.locations, API Key: AIzaSyAZhJllASbTnr......, Certificate Fingerprint: 83033D1ECACA2C88F9AA2.....
```

Comment: Have you enabled maps for android in google api console?

Comment: you should use `google map service for foryo` library if you want to use 'SupportMapFragment`

Comment: @Raghunandan yes its maps for android in google api console

Comment: @Coderji that means i have to install the google map service for froyo and uninstall the google map service?

Comment: "AIzaSyD2LVShEdbQWWV4......" is this your api key..??

Comment: @jyomin no its continued ahead

Comment: then the blank screen is because the gps is not activated on your device or the net may be not available

Comment: which version of google play service do you have used?

Comment: android:versionCode="3136110"
    android:versionName="3.1.36 (673201-10)

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee its V2

Comment: @jyomin I didnt get you

Comment: @user3146095 V2 is map version name, but do you have added updated google play service as library

Comment: @SatyakiMukerjee well the google play services library shows in the android dependencies. DO i need to add it in the libs folder as well?

Comment: I am using Google Map apiV2

Comment: @user3146095 no if it is referenced then no need to add it to libs

Comment: No no need to add it in the libs folder

Comment: @Raghunandan yes tehn its referenced. Do i need to install the google maps for froyo to make it work?

Comment: @user3146095 regenerate the key and try again.

Comment: @Raghunandan While generating the key do i need to spicify the whole package name i.e. com.abcdm.locatorapp or just com.abcdm

Comment: @user3146095 yes like `SHA;complete packagename`

Comment: @Raghunandan. I recreated the key and the key issue seems to solve it. I had not provided the complete package name. now the map shows but does not point to my current location. and I still get the Error:-The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

Comment: @user3146095 the issue is you have not referecnd the library project properly ie google play services

Comment: @Raghunandan how can I do it then?

Comment: @user3146095 tell me how you referenced the library project.

Comment: @Raghunandan I copied the Google play service library project from

C:\Users\myprofile\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject

to the desktop. Futher in eclipse imported the project from the desktop, ticked copy project into workspace. Went to my map project properties, set build tager to google api 4.4.2 and below added the google services api library to the project

Comment: You copy the library project to the folder where you android project is. them import into eclipse and then reference the same

Comment: @Raghunandan I copies the folder into the folder where by project is ie: eclipse\otherWorkspace and then tried importing it i got the error:- Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace

Comment: @Raghunandan can you post your answer for the package name change which helped resolve the map issue atleast so that i can mark it accepted

Comment: @user3146095 you can check my post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
While generating the key do i need to spicify the whole package name i.e. com.abcdm.locatorapp or just com.abcdm
```

Yes you need to mention the package name in the google api console

```
SHA;complete packagename
```

Also try regenerating the key

```
The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included
```

You need to reference the google play servies properly. Check this

[Importing google-play-service library showing a red X next to this reference android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and)

Comment: Well the first part seems to have solved the visibility of the map. Though I still get the error for google play service resources. I cheaked the link too

Comment: @user3146095 if you see the map then it is working fine. Just clean and rebuild

Comment: I did that too.. i even uninstalled the complete app from my device, clean and rebuild the project and installed it again. But at the runtime i get the same error

Comment: @user3146095 try suggestions by searching on stackoverflow. lots of similar posts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr. Also test it on a real device

Comment: @Raghunandan.. already tried all solutions on that page. didnt help though still get the error

Comment: @user3146095 i really don't know what other suggestions i can give

Answer (score 0):

Your keystore is not appropriate or package name mistake in google api console, recheck once.

Comment: I rechecked them and they look fine

Comment: Delete the key and generate new one

Comment: And in API services make all google maps services on

Comment: are you sure making all google maps services on would not result into a conflict? because there is Google maps android API and just google maps api

Answer (score 0):

Which type of keystore you are using? If you use debug key and published map looks blank. Use release key to publish.

[Google Map Android API v2 can't display map in play store application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395764/google-map-android-api-v2-cant-display-map-in-play-store-application/18395821#18395821)

Answer (score 0):

mention the entire package name with the key after semicolon ie. com.abcdm.locatorapp