# Google Maps Services not workling after publishing app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, apk

My Google maps services worked fine before I've published my application to the google play store.

But after I've published my app to the play store, the map shows nothing. It is blank.

I've Generated a signed apk and after this I've published this apk in the google play store.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have not updated the app's SHA-1 fingerprint for release certificate keystore file (using which you have signed your apk) at google developer console for the signed application.
Here are given details about release certificate and other requirements.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert

Here is another similar question asked, I hope that will help.
[Google Map Android API v2 can't display map in play store application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395764/google-map-android-api-v2-cant-display-map-in-play-store-application)